# How can I tell Firewall to allow incoming connections for Python running a specific script? (In this case: SickBeard)

Tags: firewall, python

I'm running [SickBeard](http://www.sickbeard.com) on my Lion installation, but I can't figure out how which Python version or script I should add to the Firewall rules allow connections from outside. In Console I get this message:

```
Deny Python connecting from <<external-ip:port>> to port <<my-port>> proto=6
```

So for now I've had to disable my entire firewall to allow for external control, but I'd much rather just allow Python to be connected to. I'm running Python 2.7.3 and I have already allowed the following applications to the firewall — to no avail:

- /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
- /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app
- /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
- /usr/bin/python

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

While checking the programs above I realized I hadn't added the Current alias, which was  likely used:

- /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python

Adding Python from the Current alias folder fixed my problem. Hadn't seen this question or answer anywhere else online so I'm keeping it up.